# Rewrite img src dynamically: get images from a different directory with a higher resolution

Tags: php, jquery, image, magento, src

I'm wondering what the best approach would be for the following problem, keeping page speed in mind.

1. A connector syncs product data (including product images) from retail software to a PHP-based eCommerce solution like Magento.
2. This connector only syncs product images at a 550x550 resolution.
3. There is no way to alter the connector or grab larger images from the retail solution.
4. The person in question has a directory with higher resolution images that -for arguments sake- will match the filename from the original file with an -optional- size suffix.

How can we automatically and dynamically, on page load / image load, replace the low resolution image src with the high resolution image src?

In short: how to replace `src="/path/to/low/resolution/image/shoe1.jpg` with `src="/path/to/high/resolution/image/shoe1-1024x1024.jpg"` dynamically without writing rules specifically for that single image. As in: `shoe2.jpg > shoe2-1024x1024.jpg` should also work

Additionally: we do -not- have to check for missing images in the high resolution image directory. We just want to -always- replace the low resolution source url.

I was thinking about replacing the values through javascript with/without jQuery. Would that do the job?

Comment: I would say that "replacing the values through javascript with/without jQuery" is going to be your best bet.

Comment: Well JavaScript is going to be your favorite option here. jQuery or not, its up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a jQuery solution:

```
var highRezPath = "/path/to/high/resolution/image/",
    appendToFilename = "-1024x1024";

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').each(function(ind, img){
       var $img = $(img),
           oSrc = $img.attr('src').split('/'),
           fileName = oSrc[oSrc.length-1].replace('.', appendToFilename +'.'),
           newSrc = highRezPath + fileName;
        $img.attr('src', newSrc);
    });
});
```

[See it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/7kv61f1w/) (use the web inspector to see the altered `src` attributes)

Comment: Thank you for this great solution to the problem. Does exactly what was required. Thanks!